# Citing and referencing same technology website about what one is writing, is it acceptable?

Tags: citations, website

I've to write about security issues with Microsoft Azure Cloud Services, and I find the most relevant information are on Azure website, not in any journals. Can I cite specific web-pages when I'm talking about those things? Also, if I will be doing that, I may end up citing Azure site more than 10 times at least. Is it acceptable to do that and that often?

Comment: Is this an assignment? Then it's best to ask your course instructor, who's also responsible for the grading.

Comment: yes, it is for assignment. My tutor is notoriously infamous for not responding to emails though and that's what made me ask this question here

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is acceptable, but a bit risky since MS can change those pages at any time. At a minimum, your citation needs to include the date at which you accessed the information. You can also archive the pages for your own sense of comfort or find the pages on the [Internet Archive](https://archive.org), which should be more stable.

But, for your paper to be valuable, it needs to say more than what can be found on the company's websites. If it is just restating what is there then it has no novelty and probably won't be published.